# Where does Android emulator store SQLite database - Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, sqlite

Where is the sqlite database stored? And how to get a copy of the database in Eclipse?

Comment: Please give proper problem description. What problem you are facing actually?

Comment: Don't vandalize your question, you can delete it altogether, but don't do what you just did

Answer (score 0):

1. run Eclipse
2. start your Application in the Emulator
3. go to (menu bar) Window/Show View/Other
4. go on Android/File Explorer then
5. Click on File Explorer icon
6. go to data/data/...YourAppClass.../database/YourDatabaseFile.db and select the file You want to copy to Your Disk
7. click above on the windowbar icon "pull a file from the device"
8. save the file where You want
9. You can open it in "DB Browser for SQLite"